# Why does useEffect run the first time even when it is listening to a prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I admit I will probably never understand hooks but is this assertion correct that a prop based useEffect should only run when the prop changes? In the following code both useEffects run the first time comp is rendered. Why?

```
function Comp() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("this should run once on comp load")
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("this should only run if search prop changes")
  }, [search])

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-wikm8?file=/src/index.js:111-389)

Comment: i am not sure, the given code statement is correct but, here `search`, is state which is getting changed. so second **useEffect** is getting triggered.

Comment: You can add a guard clause inside the useEffect callback - `if (search !== undefined) console.log()`.

Answer (score 2):

It seem that you misundersood how hooks work.
The official [hook effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) documentation states:

> **Does  `useEffect`  run after every render?** Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render *and* after every update. ...

So all the `useEffect` hooks will run on first render. By adding `search` dependency to your hook, you only stated that the hook should **additionally** run on each change of `search`.

If you want to disable the functionality of a hook effect on the first render then you can construct a custom hook which utilises [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook to conditionally block the initial run of the `useEffect`:

```js
const useDidUpdate = (callback, dependencies) => {
  const didMountRef = useRef(false);
  
  useEffect(() => { // block first call of the hook and forward each consecutive one
    if (didMountRef.current) { 
        callback();
    } else {
        didMountRef.current = true;
    }
  }, dependencies);
};
```

Then you would call it like:

```js
useDidUpdate(() => {
    console.log("this should only run if search prop changes")
}, [ search ]);
```